# Dynamically increase and decrease char arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I have to send data with UDP. The buffer field is of type char. I also have to encrypt/decrypt what I send. Here's my code for encrypting/decrypting.

```
const unsigned BUFFER_SIZE = 128;
char data[BUFFER_SIZE];

cout << "Enter something." << endl;
cin.getline(data, BUFFER_SIZE);
cout << data;
char outchar[BUFFER_SIZE];


for(int i = 0; i < strlen(data); i++)
{
    //outchar[i] = data[i];
            outchar[i] = encr[(int)data[i]];
            cout << outchar[i];

}

cout << "Correct so far" << endl;


char transchar[BUFFER_SIZE];
for(int j = 0; j < strlen(outchar); j++)
{
transchar[j] = decr[(int)outchar[j]];
cout << transchar[j]; // prints out decrypted text and unused space!
}
```

The problem here is that using the fixed size of char means there is a lot of unused space in the buffer. In the code provided, it gets printed to screen.

Is there anyway to dynamically increase and decrease the buffer (char array) size so that I do not get the unused space?

EDIT: Something I don't think is clear: **EVERY LETTER has to be encrypted and decrypted!** The words are not encrypted, the letters that make them up are! The advice given up to now would translate words into an array. I need the characters.

EDIT2: deleted.

EDIT3: Russians, you got to love them. Big thanks to Vlad from Moscow!

Comment: Cannot. You can't send a string through the socket.

Comment: You can use the `c_str` member function to get a pointer to the `std::string`'s internal `char` array, which you can send through a socket.

Comment: Also, 128 bytes is a very small amount of unused space...

Comment: Will I be able to encrypt/decrypt the string? 128 bytes is big when its printing 120 characters to screen.

Comment: If you want to avoid printing unused characters to the screen, you just... don't print them. Keep a count of how many characters are actually used. And yes, you can do just about anything with a `std::string` that you can do with a `char` array.

Comment: You can also use `std::vector<char> buf`, in this case you can get a pointer to the data using `&buf[0]` but you have to handle the special case when the vector is empty because then `&buf[0]` gives you subscript out of range error because indexing into an empty vector is a bug. The content of the vector is writable at the same time by default and you can declare the vector with `signed char` or `unsigned char` type too besides `char`.

Comment: @pasztorpisti Use the method `data()` instead; http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/

Comment: @Sh3ljohn My bad, you are right! :-)

Comment: This is the first time I've been more confused after coming to stack overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way is dynamically to allocate memory of a required size. Instead of doing this manually you can use standard class `std::string` To pass stored data as a char array you can use member functions `c_str()` or `data()`

For example

```
std::string data;

std::cout << "Enter something." << std::endl;
std::getline( std::cin, data );
std::cout << data;
std::string outchar;
outchar.reserve( data.size() );


for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
{
    //outchar[i] = data[i];
            outchar.push_back( encr[ (int)data[i] ] );
            std::cout << outchar.back();

}
```

To use `std::string` you need to include header `<string>`

Comment: Only problem I'm having now is how do I do that with an char array? The example here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/  just used a char pointer. Not sure how to use that to encrypt/decrypt each word.

Comment: @user106857 To encrypt/decrypt each word you have to use the std:;string object instead of character arrays.

Comment: @user106857 In the reference you gave I did not show where there is an encryption or an decryption.

Comment: That link wasn't supposed to show it. The cipher calls are in my code up op. I'M NOT ENCRYPTING WORDS! EACH LETTER IS BEING ENCRYPTED!

Comment: that code doesn't make any sense. getline(cin,s)? Is "s" supposed to be data?

Comment: Got it working! Thank you Vlad! I will support your people's claims to the Crimean for this!

Comment: "I'M NOT ENCRYPTING WORDS!" - why did you say "Not sure how to use that to encrypt/decrypt each word" then?